# mongodb-runner start socket could not be established

Tags: mongodb, parse-platform

I am setting up parse server and run mongo db in Node.js command prompt on Windows 10 following steps here: https://github.com/parse-community/parse-server.
I am able to do npm install globall, but cannot start mongo db. Getting connection reset error.

Node version v8.11.1

Tried deleting cache, but I don't see anything under 
C:\Users\username.mongodb\versions

> mongodb-runner start
>    \ Starting a MongoDB deployment to test against...{ RequestError: tunneling socket could not be established, cause=getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND 8080 8080:80
>       at ClientRequest.req.once.err (C:\Users\\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\mongodb-runner\node_modules\got\index.js:111:21)
>       at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:315:30)
>       at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
>       at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:211:7)
>       at ClientRequest.onError (C:\Users\bishnu.panda\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\mongodb-runner\node_modules\tunnel-agent\index.js:179:21)
>       at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:315:30)
>       at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
>       at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:211:7)
>       at Socket.socketErrorListener (_http_client.js:387:9)
>       at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
>     name: 'RequestError',
>     code: 'ECONNRESET',
>     host: 'fastdl.mongodb.org',
>     hostname: 'fastdl.mongodb.org',
>     method: 'GET',
>     path: '/win32/mongodb-win32-x86_64-2008plus-ssl-4.2.0.zip',
>     protocol: 'https:',
>     url: 'https://fastdl.mongodb.org/win32/mongodb-win32-x86_64-2008plus-ssl-4.2.0.zip' }
>   { RequestError: tunneling socket could not be established, cause=getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND 8080 8080:80

Comment: I think you should open an issue in the mongodb-runner repository. In the meantime, you can try to run your own MongoDB instance. Take a look in this link: https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-windows/

Comment: Thanks. Posted there.